# Form title from FormResponse

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have created a bunch of forms programmatically from a spreadsheet and bound a response trigger to each. When a form is filled out I can't seem to figure out which form was completed.

I tried:

```
Event.source.getId()
```

But that returns the id of the spreadsheet. I want to get the title of the form.

**Edit: Clarification**

This is how I set up the trigger:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('responseTrigger').forForm(form)
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

And when I try to get the title:

```
function responseTrigger(e) {
  var source = e.source;
  var title = e.source.getTitle().
  Logger.log(title);
}
```

I get the following error:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function getTitle in object Spreadsheet.

Comment: I think this might be the issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue.

There is a know [Google Scripts issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4810) that is causing my problem. You would expect `e.source.getID()` to give you the form's ID, however it gives you the spreadsheet's ID. I found a [solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505830/e-source-returns-spreadsheet-instead-of-form-object). What you do is find the unique ID of the trigger and cross reference it with all of the project triggers as follows:

```
    function getFileByTriggerId(triggerId){
      var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
      for(var i =0; i<triggers.length; i++){
       if(triggers[i].getUniqueId() == triggerId){
        return triggers[i].getTriggerSourceId();
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your response trigger you write:

```
function responseTrigger(e) {
  var realEvent = getFileByTriggerId(e.triggerUid);
  var form = FormApp.openById(realEvent);
  var title = form.getTitle();
}
```

Comment: Hmm the function `getFileByTriggerId()` is also giving me the ID of the source spreadsheet, not the ID of the form

Comment: I ended up finding the form from the sheet that the form sent the data to using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()` since it seems to set the active sheet to where the form was submitted. The sheet and form names correspond to each other so I am good to go

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

If you want to retrieve the title when the form was submitted, you can use following script.

```
var title = e.source.getTitle()
```

If you always want to retrieve the title, you can use following script.

```
var form = FormApp.openById( form ID );
var title = form.getTitle();
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error: " Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function getTitle in object Spreadsheet."

Comment: @Yehuda Solomont I'm sorry for not being helpful.

Comment: You were very helpful. Your answer is basically correct, the issue is a bug with the google service.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I could know the bug from your information. Thanks again.